# Refactoring models from one django app into two

Tags: django, django-models, refactoring

I've got an app which has grown too big and I'd like to split it into two. It's not an easy task code-wise, but I'm more afraid of the database migrations I'll have to perform. Is there a proven way of doing such kind of thing?

Currently my thoughts are something like this:

- Use south
- Copy models to another app
- Make a data migration to copy relevant models from one app to the other
- Make another migration that removes the now unused models from the old app
- Will have to make a script that does those operations in correct order

Has anybody done anything like this?

Answer (score 2):

No need to do any database migrations if you don't want to. Just set the [`db_table`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/options/#db-table) Meta attribute on your models to refer to the old names, and everything will be perfectly happy.

Comment: After some more thought, i see potential problems with south. If I understand correctly, I'll have to leave the old models alone and put "DO NOT TOUCH" warnings all over them, so south won't try to modify/delete tables...